# How can i change git account on Linux using terminal?

Tags: linux, git, gitlab

How can I change my old git account to my new git account ( on the same machine ) ? I did some research and tried to run `git user config` but it seems just change the username, not change the account.

Comment: What do you mean by Git account? The identity used when creating new local commits, or the identity used when pushing to a remote repository? There are a couple of other options too but these two are the most likely candidates. The former is controlled by `git config user.name` and `git config user.email`

Comment: By account you mean remote repository?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I clone a remote repo by a git, now i want to commit by another git. It's like you have 2 git accounts and switch them.

Comment: we can't switch two git accounts for a repo.

Comment: even if both accounts have same permission with this repo ? :(

Comment: Are you using ssh or https?

Comment: I'm using https

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this with multiple "accounts" is to have different ssh keys generated on the same machine with different credentials.